# Find the invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}(\exp(2\pi i/3))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, inverse

> Let $R=\mathbb{Z}(e^{2\pi i\over 3})$. Find $R^\times$.

**Attempt:**

Let $\zeta=e^{2\pi i\over3}$.

1. If $x^{-1}=d+e\zeta+f\zeta^2$ for some $R\times\ni x:=a+b\zeta+c\zeta^2$ then we must have
   $$
   1=ad+bf+ce
   \\0=ae+bd+cf
   \\0=af+be+cd
   $$
   But I want to find more elgant way of solving the problem.
2. Another approach is to notice that on the plain, $R$ is looking like the dots of a lot of hexagons tight to each other, but I'm not sure how it helps.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer

Comment: Looking at norms might be a good idea. Also, $\zeta^2 = -\zeta -1$, so the second degree term may be absorbed into the other two.

Comment: The hexagon is correct. It is the case $d=-3$ for the imaginary number field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d})$, see my answer.

Comment: $R[a]$ is the smallest ring containing $R,a$ and $R(a)$ is the smallest field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hints:*

- $R = \{ a+b\zeta :a,b \in \mathbb Z \}$ because $\zeta^2=-\zeta-1$.
- $\alpha \in R^\times$ iff $N(\alpha)=1$, where the norm $N(\alpha)=\alpha \bar\alpha=a^{2}-ab+b^{2}$, for $\alpha=a+b\zeta$.
- $a^{2}-ab+b^{2}=1$ implies $a,b \in \{ -1, 0, 1 \}$.

Comment: Isn't the standart norm of $\mathbb{C}\ni z=x+iy$ equals to $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt {z\bar z}$ and not to $z\bar z$ as you suggested?

Comment: @J.Doe, you're right but the one I gave has values in $\mathbb Z$, which is key. It's the standard norm in algebraic number theory.

Comment: I've followed your hints and succeed. But I wonder if there's more elgant way to show that if $a^2-ab+b^2=1$ then $a,b\in\{0,\pm1\}$. What I have came up with, is that if $1=a^2-ab+b^2$, then $$|a+b\zeta|^2_\mathbb{C}=1 \Rightarrow
\\ |a+b\zeta|_\mathbb{C}=1 $$ and all the elements in $R\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ that setesfies $|z|=1$ are $\{\pm1,\pm\zeta,\pm\zeta^2\}$, which are all setesfies $a,b\in\{0,\pm1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the following well-known lemma:

**Lemma** An element $x$ in a ring of integers is a unit if and only 
if $N(x)=\pm 1$.

**Theorem**: let $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d})$ be an imaginary-quadratic number field and $d<0$ squarefree. Then the group of units is $\mathcal{O}_K^{\times}=\mu_K$, and this cyclic group is given as follows:
$$
\mu_K=
\begin{cases}
\Bbb Z/4 =\{\pm 1,\pm i\} & \text{ if $d=-1$, } \\
\Bbb Z/6 =\{\pm 1,\pm \zeta,\pm \zeta^2\} & \text{ if $d=-3$, } \\
\Bbb Z/2 = \{\pm 1\} & \; \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

**Proof:** An element $x=a+b\sqrt{d}$ is a unit in $\mathcal{O}_K$ if and only if $N(x)=\pm 1$.
For $d\not\equiv 1 \mod 4$ we have $\mathcal{O}_K=\{a+b\sqrt{d} \mid a,b \in \Bbb Z\}$ and hence the norm condition is equivalent to the Diophantine equation 
$$
a^2-b^2d = \pm 1.
$$
For $d\equiv 1 \mod 4$ we have $\mathcal{O}_K=\{a+b(1+\sqrt{d})/2 \mid a,b \in \Bbb Z\}$ and hence $x$ is a unit iff 
$$
(2a+b)^2-b^2d = \pm 4.
$$
For $d<0$ these equations obviously have only finitely many solutions. Hence we have $\mathcal{O}_K^{\times}=\mu_K$. 
A primitive $m$-th root lies in $K$ if and only if 
$\Bbb Q(\zeta_m)\subseteq K$. Then we have 
$\phi(m)\mid [K:\Bbb Q]=2$, hence $m\mid 4$ or $m\mid 6$.
This implies the result. Of course, we can solve the Diophantine equations now directly in each case.